# Is the Zariski Topology

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

if $ K $ is an algebraically closed field, asks:
Is there a point $ "w" $ of $ K ^ n $, is closed in the Zariski toplogy?

Comment: Every point $w$ is closed, since $w$ is the zero set of the polynomials $x_1-w_1,\ldots x_n-w_n$.

Comment: I believe the answer to the question in the title is, "Yes."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is true because you can describe a point with polynomial equations.
But only in affine case the ideal of a point is maximal.